# Postman - Multiple actions were found that match the request in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have this webapi2 controller:

```
public class HomesController : ApiController
```

and I have created a customized action like this:

```
[Route("api/Homes/GetDetails")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetails(string id)
{
    var x = db.Homes.Where(b => b.HomeID == id).Select(b => new { Description = b.Description, FacebookLink = b.FacebookLink , InstagramLink = b.InstagramLink });

    if (x == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(x);
}
```

I am navigating in Postman to test this action with this URL:

```
http://localhost:59381/api/Homes/GetDetails/TEST
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

I have added this to webapiconfig:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Can anyone help me how to call this action and test it in Postman?

Comment: Can you post the full image of postman showing the full request and the response please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change attribute route to something like this:

```
 [Route("api/Homes/GetDetails/{id}")]
```

It should help.